# What's the best way to program F# on OSX 10.8?

Tags: macos, f#, osx-mountain-lion

I'm studying in university F#, and looked a bit on the internet but couldn't find a nice program to code in F#. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[F# Software Foundation](http://fsharp.org/) is a great resource to start with.

Here is an excerpt from [Using F# on Mac OSX](http://fsharp.org/use/mac/):

> #### What should I use to edit my code?
>
> Some editors have specific support for F#, either builtin or through
>   addons provided by the F# community:
>
> - We recommend [Xamarin Studio](http://xamarin.com/studio) or [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com) with the [F# AddIn for
>     MonoDevelop](http://fsharp.github.com/fsharpbinding).
> - Emacs. There is an [F# mode for Emacs](http://fsharp.github.com/fsharpbinding/) that extends Emacs
>     with syntax highlighting for F#, support for working with F#
>     Interactive and also automatic indentation.
> - VIM
> - SublimeText

While the first two options have the most up-to-date support, you can also use F# Interactive via command line and use the editor you feel the most comfortable with.

Comment: How do I use F# Interactive

Comment: After installation, F# Interactive is in system path so you can fire up F# Interactive by typing `fsharpi` in Terminal.